# Спам системной ошибки в консоли

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Когда перехожу в консольный режим (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) постоянно спамит это сообщение:

```
usb usb2-port1: Cannot disable (err = -32)
usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

В usb стоит только беспроводная мышка, все порты работают.

Как можно исправить проблему? Ну или хотя бы сделать так чтоб это сообщение не появлялось? Linux Xubuntu 16.03

Comment: найти в /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf (возможно в /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf )
что-то вроде 
       *.=warn       /dev/tty1
и закомментировать (добавить # в начало строки)

Comment: там ничего подобного нет (в дириктории /var/log/ тоже)

Comment: а в /etc/rsyslog.d/ ?
в принципе, 'ps -ax | grep syslog' должно показать какой именно логгер используется, потом в его конфиге найти или /dev/console или /dev/tty1 и заменить на то, куда хочется получать лог.

Comment: @vasily-vm, это же явно сообщения от программы *linux*, а не от программы *rsyslog*.

Comment: "rsyslogd - reliable and extended syslogd" [https://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd]
это просто другой сислог...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в файле `/etc/sysctl.conf`  есть строка

`#kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3`

Надо раскоментировать её и `sysctl -p` или ребут